# Is it possible to mediate AdMob native ads through MoPub?

Tags: admob, mopub, native-ads, mobile-ad-mediation

I have been moving towards native ads but my fill rate isn't great. I'm already mediating several native ad networks through MoPub on Android but I haven't a good example on how to mediate AdMob native ads through it. Is it even possible? the AdMob native ad configuration looks totally different from the ones that I'm familiar with (avocarrot, flurry, facebook). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Currently AdMob's custom adapter to display native ads through MoPub mediation is still in closed beta. Unfortunately you'll have to either implement a custom logic to display AdMob's ads or wait until the adapter is launched.